# vim multiple character substitute regex issue

Tags: vim, substitution

I am little new to Vim world. I am trying to substitute `*=`, `~=`(actually `[special char]=`) in to `[whatever is symbol]=`(adding space both sides). Here is my substitute command:

```
:%s/[~,\*]=/ = /g
```

the problem in this case is that I am not able to add respective special symbol before the equal sign. Can you help me...

Comment: Looks like you want something like: `:%s/\([~,\*]\)=/ \1= /g`.  The `\( \)` creates a group around the symbol, and then we reference that with the `\1` in the substitution.

Comment: ah, I was trying `$1`. thanks so for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic *capture and replace* use case. Capture the symbol part by enclosing it in `\(...\)`, and then reference it in the replacement part via `\1`. You'll find more details at `:help s/\1` (or `:help :substitute` in general):

```
:%s/\([~,\*]\)=/ \1= /g
```

Alternatively, you can *start* the match only on the `=` with `\zs`. This *asserts* that the symbol part is there, but as it isn't included in the match, you don't need to reference it:

```
:%s/[~,\*]\zs=/ = /g
```

The same trick can be applied with `\ze` at the end. As you can see, this often results in shorter commands.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the simplest answer to your question:

```
:%s/[~,\*]=/ & /
```

An`&` in the replace segment means 'entire match'.